# How to identify if gearman server is running on linux

Tags: php, gearman

I have following queries with respect to gearman server on linux

1) From command line, how can I identify if gearman server is currently running.
2) How to stop the server
3) How to start the server

Comment: First put your problem on the google anyway hope this will help you http://gearman.org/getting-started/

Comment: Manual is the way: http://gearman.org/manual/

Answer (score 0):

**How to stop / start / restart Gearman Server**

First, know the path to gearmand and gearadmin, on my server it is:

```
/usr/bin/gearmand
/usr/bin/gearadmin
```

How to STOP Gearman Server

```
gearadmin --shutdown
```

How to START Gearman Server

```
gearmand -d
```

Note: If you are not using a database to queue Gearman worker jobs, that means all pending jobs are in memory, all pending jobs will be lost when you shutdown! If you do use a database, your pending jobs will be available upon restart and will not be lost.

Hope this helps!